# Custom compileService for caching link functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, hash, typescript

I'm using `AngularJS` with `TypeScript` and I'm trying to create my own compile service that will have a caching mechanism.

Now my service is simple:
It inputs an html string, creates a hash key, checks if it exists in the cache.
If it exists, it returns the cached linking function, otherwise it creates a linking function, caches it and returns it.

It looks something like this:

```
// found this on the internet..
private createHashKey(html: string): number {
    var hash = 0, i, chr, len;
    if (html.length == 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0, len = html.length; i < len; i++) {
        chr = html.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
        hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }

    return hash;
}

public compile(html: string): ng.ITemplateLinkingFunction {
    var key = this.createHashKey(html);

    if (!this.compiledCache.containsKey(key)) {
        this.compiledCache.setValue(key, this.$compile(html));
    }

    return this.compiledCache.getValue(key);
}
```

Now I've been replacing all my `$compile(html)` calls with `compileService.compile(html)`until I got to a call that doesn't pass a string as an input param, but a `JQuery` object.

I've looked into the `angular.d.ts` file and found this:

```
interface ICompileService {
    (element: string, transclude?: ITranscludeFunction, maxPriority?: number): ITemplateLinkingFunction;
    (element: Element, transclude?: ITranscludeFunction, maxPriority?: number): ITemplateLinkingFunction;
    (element: JQuery, transclude?: ITranscludeFunction, maxPriority?: number): ITemplateLinkingFunction;
}
```

**CRAP!!!!!**

So now I need to support three `compile` overloads. 
Now since creating a hash key from a `JQuery` object is different than from a `string`, I **can't** provide "dummy overloads" like this:

```
public compile(element: JQuery);
public compile(element: Element);
public compile(element: string);
public compile(html: any): ng.ITemplateLinkingFunction {
    var key = this.createHashKey(html); // this will not work with JQuery objects

    if (!this.compiledCache.containsKey(key)) {
        this.compiledCache.setValue(key, this.$compile(html));
    }

    return this.compiledCache.getValue(key);
}
```

So I have two problems:

1. Is there any way to keep the `compile` function name over more than one implementation? I guess the answer will be no since I understand how `Typescript` works, but maybe there is a work around here. I dont want to create method names like `compileJQuery` and `compileHtml`.
2. I need to think of an elegant way to hash `JQuery` and `Element` objects as my keys and make it pretty efficient.

Any additional tip will be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var key = this.createHashKey(html);` you could do:

```
var strVal = html;
if(html instanceof jQuery) strVal = html.html();

var key = this.createHashKey(strVal);
```

Comment: Tried that already..The `html()` was empty for some weird reason while the `html` object was an array of 8 elements that contained text & html elements.

Comment: If its an array you can do something like `foo.length > 1 ? foo.each(function(){ strVal = strVal + this.html() }) : foo.html()` But its beginning to look dodgy

Comment: It's exact type is `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[8]`. This is the code that is compiled: `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` where elements is the second param a link function accepts: `this.link = function (scope, element, attr)`

Comment: The `$compile` method has 3 overloads where no one of them is an array. I have no idea what an `Element` is, but it also has an overload. BTW what you suggested with the concatination is what I started to do, but I thought is was too fishy to continue with it and I'm probally missing something small here.